# How to execute a method only once in Ruby? Are there static variables?

Tags: ruby, static

I wrote a script that contains a few method definitions, no classes and some public code. Some of these methods execute some pretty time-consuming shell programs. However, these shell programs only need to be executed the first time the method is invoked.

Now in C, I would declare a static variable in each method to make sure those programs are only executed once. How could I do that in Ruby?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is an idiom in ruby: `x ||= y`.

```
def something
  @something ||= calculate_something
end

private

def calculate_something
  # some long process
end
```

But there is a problem with this idiom if your 'long running utility' may return a false value (false or nil), since the `||=` operator will still cause the right side to be evaluated.
If you expect false values then use an additional variable, in a way similar to the proposed by DigitalRoss:

```
def something
  return @something if @something_calculated
  @something = calculate_something
  @something_calculated = true
  return @something
end
```

Don't try to save a line of code by setting the @something_calculated variable first, an then running calculate_something. If your calculate function raises an exception your function will always return nil and will never call the calculate again.

More generally, in Ruby you use instance variables. Note however, that they are visible in all the methods of given object - they are not local to the method.
If you need a variable shared by all instances, define the method in the class object, and in every instance call `self.class.something`

```
class User
  def self.something
    @something ||= calculate_something
  end

  def self.calculate_something
    # ....
  end

  def something
    self.class.something
  end
end
```

Comment: This won't work for me since I only define methods but no classes. But this is really neat! I should probably just wrap the whole thing in a class and call it a day.

Comment: This will work for you. If you don't define classes then you are working in some Object. Try `puts self.inspect; puts self.class.inspect` in your script.

Comment: Indeed, in Ruby you are always in an object, even if you don't know it, and all instance variables a visible in that scope.

Comment: @Arsen7, why not just get the method to overwrite itself with a null method after first invocation? this saves you having to keep state around and avoids the conditional. See my answer.

Comment: @banister: The state is still kept somewhere, and I (in my humble opinion) prefer the simplest, most readable solutions. The final effect will be the same, but using explicit variable gives you, for example, a chance to easily reset the state.

Comment: @Arsen7, resetting the state wasn't part of his spec. IMO your solution is the one i'd use if i was programming C or Java. In Ruby we can do better.

Answer (score 4):

The "memoize" gem might be good here.  When you memoize a method, it is called no more than once:

```
require 'memoize'

include Memoize

def thing_that_should_happen_once
  puts "foo"
end
memoize :thing_that_should_happen_once

thing_that_should_happen_once    # => foo
thing_that_should_happen_once    # =>
```

Comment: This gem has been deprecated https://github.com/djberg96/memoize. `Please do not use this gem. It has long been surpassed by other, better
  memoization gems like memoizable and memoist.`

Comment: @bithavoc Quite true!  Would you be so kind as to edit that comment into the answer, or make a new answer from that comment?

Answer (score 2):

```
def f
  system "echo hello" unless @justonce
  @justonce = true
end
```

And, hmm, if you want it to run a shell command on invocation *until it succeeds*, you might try:

```
def f x
  @justonce = system x unless @justonce
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Unlike the other solutions in this thread, this solution doesn't require you to hold onto any state:

Get the method to remove itself after invocation or to overwrite itself with an empty method:

```
def hello
  puts "hello"
  define_singleton_method(:hello) {}
end
```

OR:

```
def hello
  puts "hello"
  singleton_class.send(:undef_method, __method__)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def my_time_consuming_method
  @result ||= begin
    sleep 5
    true
  end
end

my_time_consuming_method # true after 5 secs
my_time_consuming_method # true directly
```

Answer (score 0):

Making sure shell commands are run only once is a recurring pattern. One solution I wrote, makes a checksum on the input files on the command line and only executes it when the shell command has not run before. It also executes again when input files have changed. See

https://github.com/pjotrp/once-only

Simply use it by prepending 'once-only' to the shell command. E.g.

`bowtie -t e_coli reads/e_coli_1000.fq e_coli.map`

becomes

`once-only bowtie -t e_coli reads/e_coli_1000.fq e_coli.map`

For PBS add a --pbs switch.